# Local Storage useage to get 2 same name css properties with different value

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i use the display none/block using 2 buttons , i need one to display none while other is blocked and visa versa on click ? I tried this but ofc doesn't work.

```html
<input id="widen-page" type="button" value="Go Full Width"></button>
<input id="narrow-page" type="button" value="Go Fixed Width"></button>
```

```js
$('#widen-page').on('click', function() {
    $('.pagebody').css('max-width','100%');
    $('#widen-page').css('display','none');
    $('#narrow-page').css('display','block');

    //pagebody
    localStorage.setItem('max-width','100%');
    //wide-page
    localStorage.setItem('display','none');
    //narrow-page
    localStorage.setItem('display','block');
});
$('#narrow-page').on('click', function() {
    $('.pagebody').css('max-width','');
    $('#widen-page').css('display','block');
    $('#narrow-page').css('display','none');

    //pagebody
    localStorage.setItem('max-width','');
    //wide-page
    localStorage.setItem('display','block');
    //narrow-page
    localStorage.setItem('display','none');
});
var maxwidth = localStorage.getItem('max-width');
var display = localStorage.getItem('display');
var display = localStorage.getItem('display');
$('.pagebody').css('max-width', maxwidth);
$('#widen-page').css('display', display);
$('#narrow-page').css('display', display);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, localStorage is a **key: value** store, so you need to make sure that each item you want to save there has a *unique* key. At the moment, you're conflating the two buttons into one key.

You could use `localStorage.setItem("widen_page_display","none")`, for example.

Comment: thanks, can you you illustrate that usage per my example

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
$('#widen-page').on('click', function() {
    $('.pagebody').css('max-width','100%');
    $('#widen-page').css('display','none');
    $('#narrow-page').css('display','block');
    localStorage.setItem('max-width','100%');
    localStorage.setItem('narrowmypage','block');
    localStorage.setItem('widenmypage','none');
});
$('#narrow-page').on('click', function() {
    $('.pagebody').css('max-width','');
    $('#widen-page').css('display','block');
    $('#narrow-page').css('display','none');
    localStorage.setItem('max-width','');
    localStorage.setItem('narrowmypage','none');
    localStorage.setItem('widenmypage','block');
 });
   var maxwidth = localStorage.getItem('max-width');
   var fixedwidth = localStorage.getItem('widenmypage');
   var fullwidth = localStorage.getItem('narrowmypage');
   $('.pagebody').css('max-width', maxwidth);
   $('#widen-page').css('display', fixedwidth);
   $('#narrow-page').css('display', fullwidth);
```